# How to assign function return value to a variable in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just started to play around with Rust. Trying to run the code snippet below will result in a compile time error with the message: `type ascription is experimental`.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let arguments: Args = env:args();
}
```

The docs for [`env:args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html) shows that the function returns an `Args` struct and the [Variable Binding section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/variable-bindings.html#type-annotations) shows that I can set type of the variables with `let varname: type = value`. How I can properly assign a return value of a function to a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for

```
let arguments: Args = env::args();
```

Using a single colon in an expression is type ascription, and currently you can only specify types on variable bindings. Note that the `: Args` annotation on this line is optional.

Using two colons allows you to access items within a namespace, so one wants `env::args`, not `env:args`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the purpose of using `::` to access functions in a namespace. But I don't exactly understand the reason of using `:`. I googled type ascription and I roughly understand what it means, but could you provide some example here to show what would be the purpose of using one semicolon in Rust?

Comment: @NoNameProvided Sometime a type can't be inferred. Type ascription makes it easier to specify. [Here's an example.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5306c9bb7e2c83070b5dcd48be7d4eb2&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: @Veedrac what's the difference between that and `default::Default::<String>()`?

Comment: @NateMara Using `::<String>` specifies the template parameters of `Default::default`, whereas `: Default` specifies the return type. In this trivial case those happen to be one and the same, but that's not always the case. Type ascription also looks nicer, IMO.